# Unable to send Email using Django

Tags: django, django-forms

```
Internal Server Error: /index/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/pradeep/Desktop/avinkey-pradeepavula (11)/tecum1/pr1/views.py", line 12, in index
    send_mail('subject', 'message', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['avulapradeep333@gmail.com'] , fail_silently=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 63, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 338, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Will be able to send Email from Django form

Comment: def index(request):

 if request.method == 'POST':
  message=request.POST['Message']
  send_mail('subject', 'message', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['avulapradeep333@gmail.com'] , fail_silently=False)

 return render(request,'index.html')

Comment: Don't add code in your comments. Also show us your settings.py (email settings, without showing your password).

Comment: Not allowed to add in the subject so adding in comments

DEBUG = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.in'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'pradeep.avula@tecumosolutions.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxx'
EMAIL_HOST_PORT = '587'

Comment: EMAIL_USE_TLS = True. And make sure your email host doesn't use multi-factor authentication.

Comment: @dirkgroten sorry mistakenly I skipped that code, and twofactor is not enabled.

DEBUG = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.in'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'pradeep.avula@tecumosolutions.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxx'
EMAIL_HOST_PORT = '587'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



Still not working

Comment: @dirkgroten Could you please help me